# JSON configuration toTypeScript class with Gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp

i am trying to create a typescript class from JSON configuration with gulp task.

```
input

    {
      "ApiEndpoint": "http://localhost:5000/api"
    }
```

looking to get a output like

```
  public static get ApiEndpoint(): string {
    return "http://localhost:5000/api";
  }
```

Tried using **gulp-ts-config** but its throwing a error in template.ts. Somehow i am not able to make it work in my system. Is there any other gulp plugins through we can achieve the same ?

Comment: what have you tried with `gulp-ts-config` plugin? You should know that this is no place to ask for tool recommendations.

Comment: may i know why do you want this type of output ?

Answer (score 3):

My package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-ts-config": "1.0.15"
    }
}
```

My gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpTsConfig = require('gulp-ts-config');

gulp.task('test', function () {
    gulp.src('appsettings.json')
        .pipe(gulpTsConfig('AppSettings'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts'))
});
```

appSettings.json

```
{
    "ApiEndpoint": "http://localhost:5000/api"
}
```

After running task the created typescript

```
export class AppSettings {

  public static get ApiEndpoint(): string {
    return "http://localhost:5000/api";
  }
}
```

References: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ts-config

if I change my appSettings.json to include multiple objects to convert to typescript functions

```
{
    "ApiEndpoint": "http://localhost:5000/api",
    "HelloWorld":  "HelloWorld"
}
```

Result ts file

```
export class AppSettings {

  public static get ApiEndpoint(): string {
    return "http://localhost:5000/api";
  }
  public static get HelloWorld(): string {
    return "HelloWorld";
  }
}
```

What is your specific error you receive from gulp-ts-config? I am using Visual Studio 2017 with npm version 5.5.1 and node version v8.9.3